# Scrolling programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like the cell of my JTable to be aligned horizontally with the selected panels.
Here is the a SSCCE to illustrate my problem.  Thanks for any help.

```
public class TableCellAlignment {

    private final static int MAX = 50;
    private static SelectablePanel[] selectablePanels = new SelectablePanel[MAX];
    private static JScrollPane slaveScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private static JScrollPane masterScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private static JTable slaveTable = new JTable();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableCellAlignment().createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TableCellAlignment");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(MAX, 1));
        Integer[][] objs = new Integer[MAX][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            objs[i][0] = new Integer(i);
            SelectablePanel masterSelectablePanel = new SelectablePanel();
            masterSelectablePanel.setNum(i);
            selectablePanels[i] = masterSelectablePanel;
            masterPanel.add(masterSelectablePanel);
        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(objs, new Object[]{"Column1"});
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        slaveTable.setRowHeight(20);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        model.addRow(objs);
        slaveTable.setModel(model);
        final JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        masterScrollPane.setViewportView(masterPanel);
        slaveScrollPane.setViewportView(slaveTable);
        p.add(masterScrollPane);
        p.add(slaveScrollPane);
        f.add(p);

        f.setSize(400, 200);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class SelectablePanel extends JPanel {

        private PropertyChangeSupport cs;
        private int num;
        private boolean selected = false;

        public SelectablePanel() {
            cs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
            cs.addPropertyChangeListener(new SelectedPropertyChangeListener());
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    setSelected(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public int getNum() {
            return num;
        }

        public void setNum(int num) {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (selected) {
                Color c = g.getColor();
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                g.drawString("" + getNum(), getWidth() / 2, (getHeight() + (fm.getAscent() - fm.getDescent())) / 2);
                g.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 20);
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            boolean oldVal = isSelected();
            this.selected = selected;
            cs.firePropertyChange("selected", oldVal, selected);
            repaint();
        }

        private class SelectedPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("selected")) {
                    boolean selected = (boolean) evt.getNewValue();
                    if (selected) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                            SelectablePanel masterSelectablePanel = selectablePanels[i];
                            if (i != getNum() && masterSelectablePanel.isSelected()) {
                                masterSelectablePanel.setSelected(false);
                            }

                        }
                        slaveTable.setRowSelectionInterval(getNum(), getNum());
                        final JViewport viewport = slaveScrollPane.getViewport();
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(getBounds().x, getBounds().y, 1, 1);
                        Rectangle r2 = viewport.getVisibleRect();
                        slaveTable.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, (int)r2.getWidth(), (int)r2.getHeight()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, +1 for providing the SSCCE. BTW: in real-world code, you would do the repaint in the setSelected not the listener. But then, this is only an example :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip.  I think I will edit it anyway to use JList, I think that is what mKorbel suggest me to make it clearer, but its post has been deleted.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: as I commented (deleted comment) the best question on last week...., then I only commented,  [answers are around, some with great quality, but need to know how to search here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868553/fit-all-components-from-jframe-to-actual-size-of-window/15868588#comment22600617_15868588), don't to put JComponets to the JList or JTable, only its description, String value for JButton, lets this job (painting JButton) for XxxRenderer, btw her answer crying for your upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basic math and it does not require access to the viewport:

```
// in the isSelected block of the propertyChangeListener:
JComponent current = (JComponent) evt.getSource();
slaveTable.setRowSelectionInterval(getNum(), getNum());
// get the cellRect of the selected cell
Rectangle cellRect = slaveTable.getCellRect(getNum(), 0, false);
// get the bounds of the selected panel
Rectangle panelRect = current.getBounds();
// get the visible rect of the selected panel's parent
Rectangle parentVisibleRect = ((JComponent) current.getParent()).getVisibleRect(); 
// the diff above the current (to the parent's visible rect)
int aboveCurrent = panelRect.y - parentVisibleRect.y;
// translate the cell rect 
cellRect.y = Math.max(cellRect.y - aboveCurrent, 0);
// adjust size to slaveTable's visible height
cellRect.height = slaveTable.getVisibleRect().height;
slaveTable.scrollRectToVisible(cellRect);
```

Note that this snippet assumes that the view's viewport of both the panel's parent and the table have the same size, so either remove the header from the table, or add a header to the panel's scrollPane, or use a LayoutManager which can align the viewports of the two scrollPanes.

Answer (score 4):

viewport.[setViewPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setViewPosition%28java.awt.Point%29)( pt ); [as shown here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ScrollingProgrammatically.htm).

Comment: that example is correct (astonishing in itself, coming from java2s.com ;-) but in the context of this question, there's no need to access the viewport :-)