# Fit all components from JFrame to actual size of window

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

I'm using NetBeans. How I can make all components from my window to resize to actual size of the window? Now when my window is 800x600 and I make it larger, size of all components are the same. I would like to change size of my components when I change size of open application window.

I tried to search for answer on the internet but I couldn't find good answer to my problem.

Comment: The IDE is usually not required, for better answers.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to search for answer on the internet but I couldn't find good answer to my problem.

I find that hard to believe.

Almost every other question in the forums is about laying out components. The standard answer is to use a Layout Manager. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. We can't give specific information because we have no idea what your GUI looks like.

Comment: And if you do need a `null` layout, use a `ComponentListener` to listen for `componentResized` events.

Comment: @MouseEvent, please make that a general comment. It is not necessary for my suggestion. I in no way endorse using a null layout.

Comment: @camickr  *"I find that hard to believe."*  I don't.  Sometimes I go searching on SO for 'the answer' I saw within the last 12 hours to 'that question' (asked every day) only to discover it can be abominably hard to locate the right answers unless using the right keywords.  E.G. Let's try SO for 'fit components jframe'.. Huh, ..that actually produces some very salient examples in the first page, to my surprise.  OP, what search terms, what search engine and what top hits did you get?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I think that you have to use tags, [then to ask the question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+[jframe]+%27fit+components+jframe), this is how I searching here, don't know another ..., one of reason (the most important) for my massive tag edits here

Comment: @AndrewThompson, my response was more about the "concept" of using layout managers as oppose to using "absolute layout". It is still amazing how many people can't get the hint that using a layout manager (in most cases) is better. All they have to do is read any posting on the subject.

Comment: I saw topics about layout manager and I tried to do something with it. Problem is that I don't see that this layouts do what I want so I must do something wrong. For example I would like to use BorderLayout. Is there possibility to auto resize PAGE_START and PAGE_END? In demo from site given above only LINE_START, CENTER and LINE_END are auto resized. Next think I would like to achive is adding panels using flowlayout. I would like panels to change their size depending on size of the window. Now on HD resolution the panels are very small, on 800x600 there are to large to see all inside them.

Comment: All areas of the BorderLayout automatically resize. Some resize width, some the height and the center does both. You can always create child panels with different layout managers to do what you want. You question is so vague that we can't give specific advice.